# I cant show my row if exists in one of this tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

have three tables, `AGR_SALVAGUARDAS` and `AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO` contains data but `AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT` is empty. i want to extract the `AGR_SALVAGUARDAS` items if ID_SALVAGUARDA exists in `AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO` or `AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT`, but no shows data. what is my problem?

```
SELECT SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA
FROM (  Select ID_SALVAGUARDA, ID_AMENAZA
        FROM AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO
        WHERE ID_AMENAZA = 5043) MFT,
     (  Select ID_SALVAGUARDA, ID_AMENAZA
        FROM AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT
        WHERE ID_AMENAZA = 5043) MFA,  
      AGR_SALVAGUARDAS SAL
WHERE SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA
   OR SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA
GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA
```

Im using Oracle 10g. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `left join`.  In fact, just follow a simple rule:  Never use a comma in a `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax:

```
SELECT SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA
FROM AGR_SALVAGUARDAS SAL LEFT JOIN
     AGR_MIT_FREC_TIPO MFT
     ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFT.ID_AMENAZA = 5043 LEFT JOIN
     AGR_MIT_FREC_ACT MFA
     ON SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA = MFA.ID_SALVAGUARDA AND MFA.ID_AMENAZA = 5043   
WHERE MFT.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL OR
      MFS.ID_SALVAGUARDA IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SAL.ID_SALVAGUARDA, SAL.DESCRIPCION, SAL.EFICACIA;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. My problem was the commas (and the joins xD).